# SNMP (snmpwalk) runtime "Disabling Agent MIB Loading" option?

Tags: string, net-snmp, mib

I need completely disable `MIB` text names, because it lead to multiple bugs in displaying of HEX-STRINGs.

ex.: bugs # 2147, 2168 of net-snmp never going to be solved.

The `disable-mib-loading compile-time` option looks to be exactly what I need.

But I can't suggest all of my users to recompile net-snmp package to get rid out of bugs.

When I try to delete all SNMP-related folders, snmpwalk displays results just fine, but tons of `Cannot find module ...` errors arrives before output.

How I can completely disable any MIB functionality at `runtime` (preferably .conf file) ?

Answer (score 3):

I found it. Still no .conf-file based solution, but not need to recompile tools, at least.

```
export MIBS=""
```

(based on: http://fixunix.com/snmp/174079-re-how-disable-net-snmp-cannot-find-module-errors.html)